# Expected Value Intermediate Counting Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A palindrome is chosen at random from the list of all 6-digit palindromes, with all entries equally likely to be chosen. (Recall that a palindrome is a number that reads the same forward and backwards, such as 387783. Note: Since these palindromes are being thought of as numbers, rather than simply strings of digits, it is to be understood that the leading digit, the digit in the hundred-thousands place, must be nonzero.)

What is the expected value of the chosen number?

Answer (score 3):

Each digit of the number may be thought of a random variable, with the first and last digits coming uniformly from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ (the last digit can't be 0 because of the palindrome condition), and so each of these two digits has an expected value of 5.  The other four digits come uniformly from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, and so each has an expected value of 4.5.  Expected value is additive.  Of course we must also take place value into account.  So the expected value is $(100000+1)\cdot(5)+(10000+1000+100+10)\cdot(4.5)=550000$.